# how to group duplication data value to my script

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

This is the result to my script can anyone help to group by this dates. as you can see on that image it gives 4 rows in every counter.
[This is the image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glr4K.png)

```
   SELECT DISTINCT(effectiveDate),


      IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '1',log,
      IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '1',"SICK LEAVE",
      IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '1',"VACATION LEAVE",
      IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '1',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '1','Saturday',
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '1','Sunday','')))))) as COUNTER_1,



      IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '2',log,
      IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '2',"SICK LEAVE",
      IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '2',"VACATION LEAVE",
      IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '2',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '2','Saturday',
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '2','Sunday','')))))) as COUNTER_2,


       IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '3',log,
      IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '3',"SICK LEAVE",
      IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '3',"VACATION LEAVE",
      IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '3',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '3','Saturday',
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '3','Sunday','')))))) as COUNTER_3,


        IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '4',log,
      IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '4',"SICK LEAVE",
      IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '4',"VACATION LEAVE",
      IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '4',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '4','Saturday',
      IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '4','Sunday','')))))) as COUNTER_4


    FROM schedules sched
      LEFT JOIN timesheet ON sched.empid = timesheet.empid
    WHERE sched.empid='40'
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you provide an example in text of what the output should look like? that usually helps

Comment: @stombeur the log of the user should be in group.

Comment: @stombeur  Example 7:00:00 ------- 12:00:00 ------ 13:00:00 ---- 17:00:00 and the effectiveDate should be not duplicated. as you can see the output alot of dates.

Comment: @JobertJayJaducana, can you remove tag tsql (SQL specific to Microsoft SQL Server) from the question? From what i see it appears that you are asking a question related to querying mysql databases - not Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT effectiveDate,


  sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '1',log,
  IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '1',"SICK LEAVE",
  IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '1',"VACATION LEAVE",
  IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '1',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '1','Saturday',
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '1','Sunday',''))))))))) as COUNTER_1,



  sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '2',log,
  IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '2',"SICK LEAVE",
  IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '2',"VACATION LEAVE",
  IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '2',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '2','Saturday',
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '2','Sunday',''))))))))) as COUNTER_2,


  sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '3',log,
  IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '3',"SICK LEAVE",
  IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '3',"VACATION LEAVE",
  IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '3',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '3','Saturday',
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '3','Sunday',''))))))))) as COUNTER_3,


  sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(IF(note = "REGULAR LOGGED" and counter = '4',log,
  IF(note = "SICK LEAVE" and counter = '4',"SICK LEAVE",
  IF(note = "VACATION LEAVE" and counter = '4',"VACATION LEAVE",
  IF(note = "HOLIDAY" and counter = '4',(SELECT description FROM holidays WHERE sched.effectiveDate = holidays.date),
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Saturday' and counter = '4','Saturday',
  IF(DAYNAME(sched.effectiveDate)='Sunday' and counter = '4','Sunday',''))))))))) as COUNTER_4


FROM schedules sched
  LEFT JOIN timesheet ON sched.empid = timesheet.empid
WHERE sched.empid='40'
GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

MYSQL does not allow you to distinct a result by specific columns - distinct can only be applied to entire rows so as to return unique rows. Effective date is repeated because every new combination of effective date,COUNTER_1,COUNTER_2,COUNTER_3 and COUNTER_4 is considered a distinct row.

Does the above using group by effectiveDate give you what you need?